# Maven error compiling GeoServer custom WPS

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, java, wps, compile

I'm attempting to build a custom GeoServer WPS plugin using Maven but I'm encountering issues during compilation. I've updated my POM file and added all the required dependencies, including GeoServer and GeoTools. Unfortunately, I'm still getting errors, particularly when trying to download GeoServer dependencies.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project WPS: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.geoserver:WPS:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geoserver:geoserver:jar:2.23.0 (absent): org.geoserver:geoserver:jar:2.23.0 was not found in https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geoserver-releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of osgeo-snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced.

hier my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>WPS</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WPS</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gt.version>29.0</gt.version> <!-- GeoTools version -->
        <jts.version>1.18.2</jts.version> <!-- JTS version -->
        <geoserver.version>2.23.0</geoserver.version> <!-- GeoServer version -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- GeoServer dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
            <version>${geoserver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- GeoServer dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoserver</artifactId>
            <version>${geoserver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other GeoServer dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
            <version>${gt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JTS (Java Topology Suite) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geoserver-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I definitely have an internet connection, but Maven seems to be having trouble downloading GeoServer artifacts. How can I resolve this issue? Are there additional configurations or steps that I might have overlooked?

Comment: There is no `geoserver.jar` file so it won't be fetched. You might mean `gs-main`?

Comment: i changed to gs-main and it compile correctly but i still cant see it in GeoServer Request builder. I did the same steps like for HelloWPS. I create also a nes Factory Process...do you think i need some more Depencies or this is irrelvant to show a custum wps in GeoServer

Comment: if it compiles then you don't need any more dependencies - did you look in the log file to see what the issue is? If necessary turn logging level up to GeoTools developer